# How to find mapping between buttons and callback methods?

Tags: android, android-event

I want to dynamically analyze an android application like yelp for security purposes.

I would like to find out if multiple items in the list view correspond to the same callback; if they do, I will not click these items during dynamic analysis.

Is there any way to find out mapping between UI elements and callback methods?

I am exploring Androguard but haven't come across a specific solution.

Appreciate your comments.

Comment: My answer will not probably help you directly but maybe make you food for thought. I think the benefit to sometimes not click on a UI element vs the cost of developing a static analysis script that maps the UI elements with the callback is negligible, even for large scale dynamic analysis. I.e. your time will be probably better spend on another problem.